# Adding WCF Service Does Not Add Meaningful configuration.svc.info

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

VS 2015/WPF App

I know there are dozens of other questions about adding service references but I haven't seen any other problem like this one.

I can add the service reference and it generates the client side proxies just fine and I can get intelense support when constructing it.

But when trying to invoke the service I get the dreaded

***Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.NAMEOFSERVICE' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.***

So after looking through the dozens of the other questions on SO I looked at the configuration.svcinfo for the new service and find this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurationSnapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-wcfconfigurationsnapshot">
  <behaviors />
  <bindings />
  <endpoints />
</configurationSnapshot>
```

The other services I've been adding have a configuration.svcinfo file that looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurationSnapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-wcfconfigurationsnapshot">
  <behaviors />
  <bindings>
    <binding digest="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data name=&quot;ServiceSoap&quot;&gt;&lt;security mode=&quot;Transport&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;" bindingType="basicHttpBinding" name="ServiceSoap" />
    <binding digest="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data name=&quot;ServiceSoap1&quot; /&gt;" bindingType="basicHttpBinding" name="ServiceSoap1" />
  </bindings>
  <endpoints>
    <endpoint normalizedDigest="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data address=&quot;https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v11&quot; binding=&quot;basicHttpBinding&quot; bindingConfiguration=&quot;ServiceSoap&quot; contract=&quot;ServiceReference2.ServiceSoap&quot; name=&quot;ServiceSoap&quot; /&gt;" digest="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data address=&quot;https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v11&quot; binding=&quot;basicHttpBinding&quot; bindingConfiguration=&quot;ServiceSoap&quot; contract=&quot;ServiceReference2.ServiceSoap&quot; name=&quot;ServiceSoap&quot; /&gt;" contractName="ServiceReference2.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
  </endpoints>
</configurationSnapshot>
```

So basically the configuratione.svcinfo for this new service is empty.

Of course the app.config file doesn't have anything about this new service either.

Does anyone have any idea why VS would create the proxies successfully but not bother to create the configuration.svcinfo?

Comment: Do you have a misspell?

Comment: Not that I can see. I removed the actual name of the service from my post as it it's public yet. All the code being generated by Visual Studio is being done with me just entering the URL of the service and I know I'm not typoing that since I can see all the proxies that it's generating correctly.